# How to use "AsEnumerable()" on datatable in Azure function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

After getting the details from the DB in a [data-table], I am trying to convert it to Enumerable using "AsEnumerable()" though getting an error message.
I think I added all the assemblies required. Following is the error I am getting. Not able to find anything, any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try referencing both "System.Data" and "System.Data.DataSetExtensions" (no need to reference Linq too).

[image]

Comment: Hello @Marie, Thanks.
Already tried that though got error message (The type or namespace name 'DataSetExtensions' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data')

Comment: Ah my bad, Tried one more time after your comment and somehow it is working now :)
Thanks

Comment: glad to hear! np!